# Why is my "Incidents" link in Gitlab not appearing?

Tags: gitlab

i am unable to view the incidents for many repos in my gitlab organisation.

i have enabled the "monitor" switch in my repo settings which did enable the Monitor subheading, but i cannot see "incidents" underneath that.

has anyone else seen this issue before?[image]